# Removing invalid marker from input field

Tags: html, angularjs

So, I have an input field that sends up a flag if the entered text is not exactly seven digits long. I used oninvalid to give it a customized error message if you try to save the data with a shorter string. The problem is that, once triggered, it will retain the red border and the error message, even after a valid string has been entered and the save button pressed again. Fields without customized error messages work fine. Any ideas what might be causing this, or a way to force it to clear the invalid flag?

Worth noting, I am not actually using a submit call, but making an angularJS call instead.

```html
    <form name="myForm" class="myForm" required>
    <input name="barcode_num" size="7" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="7" ng-required="ctrl.barcodeRequired" ng-model="ctrl.barcode" pattern=".{0}|.{7}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Barcode must be exactly 7 characters')" />
    ....
    <button ng-click="ctrl.submitButton()" type="submit">SAVE</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out [docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) and [docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). These details how to use the built in angular form controller to hide and show errors and classes.

Essentially you can use a span for the error, and using the built in `$error` properties, you can display the message like so:

```
<span ng-show="myForm.barcode_num.$invalid">Barcode must be exactly 7 characters</span>
```

And in your input, you can use `ng-class` to have angular update your classes. You can add the class for the red border like so:

```
<input ... ng-class="{ 'red-border-class': myForm.barcode_num.$invalid }" />
```

If you read through those docs, you will see there are numerous different validation properties. You can validate the entire form or each named input. You can also have multiple spans for showing different error messages.